# How is it possible not to hit the next line of code during debugging?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to understand how it's possible that lines 114, 117, or 118 don't get hit in this scenario:

[image]

When stopped at line 113, I hit F10, and then... nothing. The Visual Studio debug session is still alive because the Stop Debugging button is active. And I have VS set to break on all exceptions.

What possible reasons could there be for this behavior?

Comment: Are your PDB files up to date? Also, I suspect that `Parallel.ForEach` can throw an exception, and I don't see a `try/catch` block around it.

Comment: It seems there is a deadlock when the second cycle starts, but actually I don't know why this could happen...

Comment: If you hit pause on the debugger is it still  in the `Parallel.foreach()` loop?  It looks like it is hitting a deadlock/infinite loop

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I'm assuming the PDBs would have to be up to date because this is all in one solution, and this part of the code hasn't changed in a long time. I wrapped a `try/catch` around the `Parallel.ForEach` and still get the same behavior. The `catch` block isn't hit.

Comment: @Saggio: I hit pause and the `Parallel.ForEach` is highlighted in green. When I hover over the little green arrow next to the code, it shows this: "This is the next statement to execute when this thread returns from the current function."

Comment: So, `Parallel.ForEach()` is still waiting for one or more tasks to complete. It's not surprising that when you step out of the anonymous method for the parallel tasks, you're returned to some other thread...that thread has no more user code for you to step through. But the question is, what's making `Parallel.ForEach()` wait? You can find out when you are paused in the debugger by opening the "Threads" debug window and inspecting each thread to see where it is and what it's doing.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Okay, so basically the issue is that I'm waiting on the `Parallel.Foreach()`. And something within that is still doing something. That's why lines 114, 117, or 118 aren't getting hit. Work is being done, or something is stuck, and the work within the `Parallel.ForEach()` is simply not done yet.

Comment: Please show the code with the surrounding try/catch, and show where you set the breakpoint within that catch.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Unfortunately, I don't think that would be helpful, as the `try/catch` is way back in `Main` of the console test app. I think there are too many places in code that could stop the exception from bubbling up that far. Anyway, it was just a basic `try/catch` with the `catch` writing the exception to the console.

Comment: By the way, while I still don't know the root cause, wrapping the code in a `Task` allows the process to continue: `Task.Factory.StartNew(LoggingMonitorApplication.StartService, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);`